# How to merge documentation examples within a topic or otherwise address duplicates?

Tags: discussion, documentation

I've noticed highly overlapping examples being approved.

For instance, [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/r/2471/rodbc/11560/sql-server-management-database-connection-to-get-individual-table#t=201607260216539706563) showed how to connect to a SQL Server database in R using `RODBC`. From what I can tell someone [came along later](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/r/2471/rodbc/13103/connecting-to-relational-databases#t=201607260216539706563) and decided to improve on a it a bit by copying it, adding better narrative, and providing a link to show how to make `RODBC` work with other types of databases. A clue that it transpired in this way was that both examples contained the same inconsistent formatting (I proposed an edit to fix that, so it may be gone by the time you read this).

I agree that the newer example is an improvement over the older one, however it should've been made as a change to the original example rather than the creation of a new one.

What's the best way to handle this? Is there a way to merge them so that both contributors can still receive credit, without inflicting the duplicates on Documentation users?